# Is using strict with an empty list equivalent to not using strict at all?

Tags: perl

TLDR: See question title.

In the [original version of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40400444/1), there was `use strict ();` at the top of the program. No variables were declared with `my`. The program worked. I pointed that out that the code wouldn't work because of the missing `my`s, but it turns out I was mistaken.

```
$ perl e 'use strict (); $foo = 1'
```

This program works. It doesn't crash. But obviously this crashes:

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; $foo = 1'
Global symbol "$foo" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $foo"?) at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

My first idea was to deparse it to see if something else is going on.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'use strict (); $foo = 1'
use strict ();
$foo = 1;
-e syntax OK
```

But it's not. Then it got me thinking, you can do `use strict 'vars'`, which *only* turns on the vars *thing*<sup>1</sup>. It obviously does that by calling [`import`](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/perl-5.24.0/lib/strict.pm#L62).

The `use strict` is the same as `BEGIN { require strict; strict->import; }`, so the same rule that goes for modules should apply for pragmata too. If I do `use Foo ()`, nothing is imported. Hence, `use strict ();` should be the same as `require strict;`, just at run time, because nothing is imported.

```
$ perl -e 'require strict; $foo = 1'
```

This doesn't crash. But then at runtime you cannot turn on stuff that is supposed to be set at compile time.

So what does this actually do? When Perl reaches my actual code, it probably already encountered the `strict` pragma somewhere else, so it wouldn't load it again. And it doesn't import anything.

```
$ perl -e 'print %INC'
```

Oops. This prints nothing. `%INC` is empty. But if we use another module, there is something in it.

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper \%INC'
$VAR1 = {
          'warnings.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.22/warnings.pm',
          'overload.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.22/overload.pm',
          'Carp.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.22/Carp.pm',
          'strict.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.22/strict.pm',
          'overloading.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.22/overloading.pm',
          'constant.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.22/constant.pm',
          'bytes.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.22/bytes.pm',
          'Data/Dumper.pm' => '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/Data/Dumper.pm',
          'XSLoader.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.22/XSLoader.pm',
          'Exporter.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.22/Exporter.pm',
          'warnings/register.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.22/warnings/register.pm'
        };
```

If we load Data::Dumper, `strict` was loaded at some point. But not in the pure `-e` example.

```
$ perl -e 'use strict (); print %INC'
strict.pm/usr/share/perl/5.22/strict.pm
```

Ok. This loads strict.pm.

```
$ perl -e 'require strict; print %INC'
strict.pm/usr/share/perl/5.22/strict.pm
```

So does that. But still, none of the `strict` things are enabled.

So the question really is, is `use strict ()` equivalent to just not having a `use strict` statement at all, or is there something else happening?

---

<sup>1) [perldoc strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) refers to the three different arguments `strict` can take as *things*</sup>

Comment: [Looking at CPAN for `use strict ();` and similar](http://grep.cpan.me/?q=use+strict%5Cs*%5C%28%5C%29) gives us a few hits. While [HTTP::PAI](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::OAI) [claims](https://metacpan.org/source/TIMBRODY/HTTP-OAI-4.03/CHANGES#L59) to do it, the actual code only has `use strict;`. There are three distributions though that explicitly don't import anything from `strict`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use strict ();
```

(essentially) doesn't do anything: see [the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html):

> If you do not want to call the package's import method (for instance, to stop your namespace from being altered), explicitly supply the empty list:
>
> `use Module ();`
>
> That is exactly equivalent to
>
> `BEGIN { require Module }`

Of course, `strict` only does something if you call its `import` method (which you can easily verify by reading its source code; it's only about 150 lines long).  So bypassing the `import` method bypasses the entire effect of `use strict`.